# Why i am not able to get Default design Implementations(templates) immediately:

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am new to azure

I was following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvsOzji_8ow  and then I completed every step till creation step
Then when I open the logic app I am not getting any default design.
If anyone knows any reason on why I am the only one not getting, please explain it will be helpful.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSJ0w.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You can get this Default design templates in Consumption plan of Logic-Apps :***

[image]

You can follow this [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/microsoft-azure-creating-a-logic-app-of-consumption-type/) for example.